# Java vs C output

Tags: java, c

This might seem simple but it's just stumbled me and my friends...

lets take the following piece of code-
in java

```
//........

int a=10;
a= a-- + a--;
System.out.print("a="+a);
//........
```

in c

```
//........

int a=10;
a= a-- + a--;
printf("a= %d",a);
//.......
```

where in the former case you get output as 19 in C you get it as 18.
the logic in c is understandable but in java?

in java if its like

```
int a=10;
a=a++;
```

in this case the output is 10.

So what's the logic?

Comment: Looks like: a=a++; ==> tmp=a; a=a+1; a=tmp;

Comment: ok so what about a=a++;
for a=10 what should be the output?

Comment: hey guys, what about the last bit of the question?

a=10;
a=a++;
...print a

its showing 10 as output?? should it not be 11?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`a = a-- + a--` causes undefined behaviour in C. C does not define which decrement should be evaluated first.

`a--` evaluates to the value of a, and after that it decrements a,
so in Java `a = a-- + a--` evaluates like this:

a = (10, decrement a) + (9, decrement a)

The second operand is 9 because first term caused a to be decremented.

In summary: With that expression, C does not define the evaluation order. Java defines it to be from left to right.

Comment: If I understand a will be 19. The last decrement isn't effective for the result.

Comment: Yes, the last decrement does not show up because right after that we assign 19 to a.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about Java but in C that line of code doesn't have a return value defined in the standard. Compilers are free to interpret it as they please.

Answer (score 2):

In the expression

```
a = a-- + a--;
```

you have a lot of sub-expressions that need to be evaluated before the whole of the expression is evaluated.

```
a = a-- + a--;
          ^^^ <= sub-expression 2
    ^^^       <= sub-expression 1
```

What's the value of sub-expression 1? **It's the current value of the object `a`.**
What's the value of the object `a`?

If the sub-expression 2 was already evaluated, value of object `a` is 9, otherwise it is 10.

Same thing for sub-expression 2. Its value can be either 9 or 10, depending on whether sub-expression 1 was already evaluated.

**The C compiler** (don't know about Java) **is free to evaluate the sub-expressions in any order**

So let's say the compiler chose to leave the `--`s for last

```
a = 10 + 10;
a--; /* 19 */
a--; /* 18 */
```

but on the next compilation the compiler did the `--`s up front

```
/* value of sub-expression 1 is 10 */
/* value of sub-expression 2 is 9 */
a = 10 + 9; /* a = 9 + 10; */
```

or it could even save one of the `a--` and use that for the final value of `a`

```
/* sub-expression 1 yields 10 and sets the value of `a` to 9 */
/* so yield that 10, but save the value for the end */
a = 10 + ???;
a = 18???; a = 19???;
/* remember the saved value */
a = 9
```

**Or, as you invoked undefined behaviour, it could simply replace your statement with any of the following**

- a = 42;
- /* */
- fprintf(stderr, "BANG!");
- system("format C:");
- for (p=0; p<MEMORY_SIZE; p++) *p = 0;
- etc ...

Answer (score 0):

You are post-decrementing. To me, the java result makes more sense.

The first a-- is evaluated as 10, and decrements to 9. 10 is the value of this sub-expression.

The second a-- is evaluated. a is now 9, and decrements to 8. The value of this sub-expression is 9.

So, it becomes 10 + 9 = 19. The two decrements get overwritten by the assignment.

I'd expect 18 if the expression were a= --a + --a.

Have you tried compiling the C version with different optimization flags?

Comment: I'd expect **17** for `--a + --a`, as that should be 9 + 8.

Comment: `--a + --a` in C could easily be `16`.  It's up to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 10 + 9
```

you can try with:

```
a = a-- + a-- + a--
```

it returns 27 ( 10 + 9 + 8)...

Answer (score 0):

```
a= a-- + a--;
```

This invokes undefined behaviour in C/C++. You should not expect consistent results from this statement.